# How can I reference environment variable in http.conf of Apache under mod_proxy settings

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

How can I reference environment variable in http.conf of Apache under mod_proxy settings?  I set targetserver as environment variable but apache mod_proxy couldn’t resolve.  Any thoughts?

```
Configuration:
ProxyPass /lac/ http://${targetserver}/
```

Error message received from server

```
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET /lac/.
Reason:
DNS lookup failure for: ${targetserver}
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Apache/2.4.12 and I am able access environment variable using ${ENV_VARIABLE_NAME} for example: ${targetservername}

Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix)

Server built:   Apr 28 2015 10:58:48